# Export custom HTML template

Tags: html, jasper-reports, export

## Background

Exporting to HTML generates the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <style type="text/css">
            a {text-decoration: none}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body vlink="#000000" text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <!-- The report -->
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Problem

The report is centered on the page, but should be left-aligned.

## Former Solution

Using JRHtmlExporter's HTML_HEADER parameter looked promising, but the classes have been [deprecated](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporter.html). This was the solution:

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER, 
    "<html>"+
    "<head>"+
    "  <title></title>"+
    "  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>"+
    "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/jasper.css\" />"+
    "  <style type="text/css">"+
    "    a {text-decoration: none}"+
    "  </style>"+
    "</head>"+
    "<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">"+
    "<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">"+
    "<tr><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">");
exporter.exportReport();
```

Now I have to use the `net.sf.jasperreports.export.HtmlExporter` and `net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration` classes, in this way:

```
HtmlExporter exporterHTML = new HtmlExporter();
SimpleExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(report.getJasperPrint());
exporterHTML.setExporterInput(exporterInput);
HtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out);
exporterHTML.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput );

SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration reportExportConfiguration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
reportExportConfiguration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
reportExportConfiguration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
exporterHTML.setConfiguration(reportExportConfiguration);

exporterHTML.exportReport();
```

How would you fix this?

## Environment

- JasperReports v5.5.2
- Java v1.6.0_38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HTML_HEADER` parameter of JRHtmlExporterParameter was replaced with:

> [`HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader()`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/HtmlExporterConfiguration.html#getHtmlHeader())

For example:

```
public byte[] exportHtml(final JasperPrint print) {
    final Exporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    exporter.setConfiguration(createHtmlConfiguration());
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out));
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
    exporter.exportReport();

    return out.toByteArray();
}

private HtmlExporterConfiguration createHtmlConfiguration()
        throws IOException {
    SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration shec
            = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();

    shec.setHtmlHeader(getHtmlHeader());
    shec.setHtmlFooter(getHtmlFooter());

    return shec;
}

private String getHtmlHeader() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<head>");
    sb.append("  <title></title>");
    sb.append("  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>");
    sb.append("  <style type=\"text/css\">");
    sb.append("    a {text-decoration: none}");
    sb.append("  </style>");
    sb.append("</head>");
    sb.append("<body text=\"#000000\" link=\"#000000\" alink=\"#000000\" vlink=\"#000000\">");
    sb.append("<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">");
    sb.append("<tr><td align=\"left\">");

    return sb.toString();
}

private String getHtmlFooter() {
  // Close the opening tags from getHtmlHeader()...
}
```

Even better would be to use external resources (such as a database, file, or web page) for the HTML content, rather than hard-coded strings.