# How can I add a button in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to add a button in the report, which any action will be fixed?

Example: Button "View", which will show more detailed statistic.

[image: Example button]

Comment:

*I do not absolutely understand how it is possible to make a button of a text element*

Comment: you need to be more specific, you are just asking how to add a button.What is your exact problem?

Comment: I have dashboard. I need to add the button, when pressing on which, there is a certain action. It is possible to make it in jasper? Thanks

Comment: Sure, its possible use the anchor expression on the textElement. If still trouble's past some jrxml code, with current behavoiur, desired behaviour. (edit the question, link under question)

Comment: Thanks, Petter. You couldn't, give an example or give the reference where it is described?

Comment: I yet not absolutely understand how it is possible to make the button of a text element

Comment: Next time @Petter in comment so I can see it automatically... I posted an answer lets see if you like it....

Comment: Yes, @Petter. Thank You. I am very grateful you for the help. But, as far as I understand, I can add this button to dashboard in the form of the report. I had one more question. Whether I on this button can add the dropping-out list?

Comment: You need to use javascript (it will only work in html), find the button (similar as below in ccs) document.getElementById("idBtn") attach your new action and behavior that you like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a **button**, create a `textField` with `hyperlinkType="Reference"`  and a `hyperlinkReferenceExpression`

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JddButton" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2a88eaae-fbef-4a3d-b8bf-0b12bafc985b">
<title>
    <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="150" y="20" width="200" height="40" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#009900" uuid="822deecb-059b-4921-bfb7-07ee7cbde26a">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="btn"/>
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="idBtn"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="24"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["VIEW"]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["myButton"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292302/petter-friberg"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Click to view"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Will generate**

[image: Result]

when clicked it will direct you to the value of the `hyperlinkReferenceExpression`, in example I have also set `hyperlinkTarget="Blank"` so it opens in a new page.

For additional information on the attributes see [JRHyperLink API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRHyperlink.html)

***Hey I want my button to change color when I pass over it....***

No problem, (as long as export is html, in pdf you need to do some tricks with annotation but I will leave this out..).

I have added some css tags on the `textElement` see the property under the `reportElement`

So some simple css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none}
    td.btn:hover {
        background-color: yellow !Important;
    }
</style>
```

Finally, *how do I put this css in the output file?*

[Export custom HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612975/jasperreports-exporting-html-modify-default-html-template)

[How to add css to jasper report server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/working-css-files)