# execute drill down jasper report in pop up JasperReports Server

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

How to execute drill down sub report as a pop up in the same window?
Now it is drilling down in the same window of *JasperReports Server*.
Below is the code :

```
<textField hyperlinkType="ReportExecution"> 
   <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#2471D6" uuid="dcbcfbd0-98a4-4c94-a7a5-01ff9bff8db8"/> 
   <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"> <font isUnderline="true"/> </textElement> 
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{resourceunique1}]]></textFieldExpressio‌​n> <hyperlinkParameter name="_report"> 
   <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA["jrepo:/ca_ppm/ReportsCustom/sub‌​Reports/ResourceCapacityGridByProjectReport"]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
</textField>
```

I need pop up in the parameter "_report" can I directly give the javascript inside the "_report" parameters expression. If so, can you please lead me to achieving it

Comment: If popup you need to use javascript, if new window you can use target="_blank", post relevant part of jrxml (where you have the link to drill into subreport)

Comment: You should the edit question (not pass as comment), anyway what do you need the complex popup window or just a new window?

Comment: I need pop up in the parameter "_report"  can I directly give the javascript inside the "_report" parameters expression..If so.can you please lead me to achieving it

Comment: ok thank you #Petter

Comment: Hmm popup is not the simplest to do when you have hyperlinkType="ReportExecution", you can use hyperlinkTarget="Blank" but this will not popup, it will just open a new window.... to popup you probably need to attach a javascript to the header, that find your link and transforms into a popup...

Comment: The normal popup code would be javascript:window.open("+"\'http:\\\\www.google.com\'"+","+"\'\'"+","+"\'height=480,width=950,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no\'"+");", but I highly doubt this will work on hyperlinkType="ReportExecution"

Comment: can you please elaborate the steps to add hyper link to the header

Comment: I was mostly a comment but you can add a java script to the header of your html, and then if you use the property net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class you will be able to find your links with the javascript and you can change them to open in window... However I'm not a javascript expert... see this to understand how to attach class ecc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673513/how-to-add-button-in-report/34682075#34682075

Comment: I would go for the hyperlinkTarget="Blank" and then take some coffee. ;.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a report in a popup window by filling in the Hyperlink tab in Jaspersoft Studio with these values. Note you need add your server URL:

- Link Target: Self
- Link Type: Reference
- Hyperlink Reference Expression: "javascript:void(window.open("jasperserver-url/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/public/Resources/Reports/ca_ppm/ReportsCustom/sub‌​Reports/ResourceCapacityGridByProjectReport&decorate=no'" +","+"\'\'"+","+"\'height=480,width=950,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no\'"+"));"

Comment: Thanks for your effort #jtsnr.But I am executing a report when the hyperlink is clicked and am also passing 3 parameters with the link.so  need to pass the parameter to the drill down report.Can I pass it direclty to the "_report" parameters expression

Comment: You can pass the parameters with this - just add them onto the end of the URL e.g. /public/Resources/Reports/ca_ppm/ReportsCustom/sub‌​Reports/ResourceCapacityGridByProjectReport&decorate=no&param1=someval&param2=someval2

Comment: But how can I pass the parameters that I set with the link using this method .I tried the above method but it is just popping up the input control window with the parameter given through URL.what I want is ,I need to pass separate parameter like ($P{year},P${month}) through the link

Comment: okay so you would need to concatenate something like this to the URL part: &decorate=no&year_param='" + $P{year} + "&month_param=" + $P{month}

Comment: hey #jtsnr thanks again for your help I am getting the pop up with input controls,but the pop up is not executing report its just filling the report with the parameters and wait for the user to press ok .What I want is I dont want to lead into the sub reports input control window rather i executes the report.

Comment: here is my expression :--  "javascript:window.open("+"\'http://servername:8080/reportservice/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Forganizations%2FCareFirst%2Fca_ppm%2FReportsCustom%2FsubReports&reportUnit=%2Forganizations%2FCareFirst%2Fca_ppm%2FReportsCustom%2FsubReports%2FResourceCapacityGridByProjectReport&decorate=no&year="+$P{year}+"&month="+$P{month}+"&resource="+$V{resourceunique1}+"'" +","+"\'\'"+","+"\'height=480,width=950,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no\'"+");"

Comment: I think the fact that the report waits for the user to click OK is to do with how you create the parameters in JasperServer. If you have the Mandatory checkbox selected then JasperServer will prompt the user to click OK before running the report.

Comment: T@jtsnr Thanks again man .It work's for me.A small issue remains after getting the pop up the main report which contain the hyperlink disappears and it shows a text  "[object]" in the main page

Comment: It worked .After giving return(false) in JavaScript. Thanks alot

Comment: Great. Glad it worked. Also I think using javascript:void(window.open(...)) would fix the "[object]" problem