# How to export fonts in Gujarati-Indian Language to pdf?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I wanted to show different fonts(Gujarati-Indian Language) in Exported report of PDF from jasper report version 5.1.

What i have tried :
After Running Tool open below location
Step 1:

Tools -> Option -> Fonts

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=Arial Unicode MS - the default     font name.
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size=10 - the default font size.
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=Identity-H - the default PDF font.
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=UTF-8 - the default PDF character encoding.
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=true - by default PDF fonts are not embedded
```

Fonts "Arial Unicode MS" installed and its jar file also created.Jar files exits in class path of jasper report.

Link Followed :1) [Fonts](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension) 
2) [Sample fonts](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/)

Step 2 : irfonts.xml

By default jasper report gives other fonts in this file i changed it to.

```
<fontFamily name="Arial Unicode MS">
<normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/ArialUnicodeMS.ttf</normal>
<pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
<pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
```

Step 3:

What result i am getting:
હીપ્સ
What i actually wanted:
હિપ્સ

After Spending some time i came to know when you render a page in Template of Jasper report Fonts are working as per need but when you export it to pdf it changes Reason all the fonts goes through "itext pdf engine".

Now, trick is itext do not have fonts what I am currently using.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this.

Notes:
It's not created using Java.I'm a Oracle Database Developer so created using tool only and printing withing tools boundaries.

Followed this blog also but it is in java so don't know where make changes.
[Blog of java](http://rkvsraman.blogspot.in/2009/05/indic-scripts-and-jasper-reports.html)

Sample Code:

```
<textField>
<reportElement x="111" y="26" width="100" height="20" uuid="5a471a16-de7b-4f55-9c9f-b01d37938b9f"/>
 <textElement>
    <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{my_column_values}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Some the similar questions are also in stack overflow but all of them uses java to call and print.

So, can I change itext library or any other workaround will be fine.
How i created :

1) [Jasper report](http://oracleexplain.blogspot.in/2016/04/printing-with-jasper-soft-ireport_11.html)

2) [Jasper](http://oracleexplain.blogspot.in/2016/04/printing-with-jasper-soft-ireport.html)

Comment: `I'm a Oracle Database Developer so created using tool only and printing withing tools boundaries.` - What is your way for generating reports using JasperReports? And what is your task(s)?

Comment: Based on Data Source which will use my data base Columns and based on column i have created Report to render data.

Comment: You can check out this to narrow down your problem [How can I test my font in pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf) and the problem of rendering with [ligatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295596/font-myanmar3-not-rendering-correctly-in-itext)

Comment: Note you need to **use font-extensions** check out this [how-can-i-render-hindi-correctly-when-exporting-to-pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287186/how-can-i-render-hindi-correctly-when-exporting-to-pdf)

Comment: Try to narrow it down, then you need to provide a [mcve], a minimal jrxml (also without data, for example use title band and a parameter), link to ttf font, current result and expected result. That way we get a great question and can provide you with a decent answer.

Comment: @Petter Friberg About first first comment its checking using JAVA code how can check without using java.. i am not familiar with it. Font Extension would be <a href="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions">Font Ext</a> if yes i have done this as i mention in my question.

Comment: How are you using jasper-reports?, itext, jasper-reports are java we have not much choice. Try to put together the [mcve] and I can test,  (I need .ttf  font and the text you need to print).

Comment: @Petter Friberg About first comment its checking using JAVA code how can check without using java.. i am not familiar with it. Font Extension would be http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions if yes i have done this as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Petter Friberg give me your email i'll send all docs.

Comment: :29933796 You can Download .ttf file from http://www.myfontfree.com/arial-unicode-ms-myfontfreecom126f36926.htm its Arial Unicode MS. What result i am getting: હીપ્સ What i actually wanted: હિપ્સ...You can test it with Static text as my data is based on Data source.

Comment: Ok I will run a test

Comment: Thanks...let me know if you anything

Comment: I have same problem running latest version of jasper-reports (reverted back to i-text 2.1.7) , I guess itext have problem with the font (tonight I will not study why), Quick solution, switch font .tff

Comment: Only Arial Unicode MS shows fonts what i needed. I tried to install font Code2000 but after installing it jasper studio crashes i can not see designer window. Jasper report version 5.1 which i am using

Comment: I have test also with latest version of iText (without jasper reports), same problem, you need to switch font our contact iText directly : )

Comment: Which font you suggest i am out of ideas right now..

Comment: Sorry, I do not really know, I can only search on google and someone told me maybe some Latha font

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting what i am missing this problem wasted my 3 damn freaking days.

Comment: Can we print from HTML..like right now i am able to generate HTML file but is it possible i can add a button on HTML page and that will open Chrome Print window. I had followed this.

Comment: @PetterFriberg can we put print button on html page i was following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673513/how-can-i-add-a-button-in-jasper-report

Comment: @PetterFriberg adding a tag in the hope that one particular person may notice a question is really frowned upon. In particular if the question lies outside that persons field of expertise. This question is about `jasper-reports`, I see nothing in the original question that relates to `itext`.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I see in the comments that, according to your research, the problem could be in iText, but unfortunately you do not share your findings. Please start a new question with all the details you found, and leave out anything related to jasper-reports.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, Thanks for your interest, I will do a new question with [mcve] so you can see the problem, sorry for adding tag (it was a quick and dirty fix : )

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655923/why-is-the-gujarati-indian-text-not-rendered-correctly-using-arial-unicode-ms

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for opening up a new question how ever i dont have that much of reputation to comment in that Question section...I would like to see if this GujaratiLigaturizer can be done with in Jasper report it self as you know i'm not using java to call print from resource bundle. Thank you.

Comment: @petterfriberg okay !!

Answer (score 2):

I create a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655923/why-is-the-gujarati-indian-text-not-rendered-correctly-using-arial-unicode-ms) only related to itext as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600311/jasper-report-pdf-export-font-of-different-language#comment60879352_36600311) by @AmedeeVanGasse I will show in this anwer how  [Alexey Subach answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657945/5292302) could be implement in jasper reports.

> **NOTE**:  Alexy Subach states that *"the implementation is really poor
>   and you cannot expect to get correct results with it"*

## Strategy 1: You only need to export pdf

Add to classpath itext5 library (note latest jasper report use itext2, you will need both) and define the `GujaratiLigaturizer` class as an variable, then process your text every time you need to output.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FontTest" columnCount="5" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="111" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2347c131-1884-430a-b77f-59f08f896c8a">
    <variable name="g" class="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.languages.GujaratiLigaturizer">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.languages.GujaratiLigaturizer()]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="25">
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="25" uuid="ee49d149-394b-4ac6-a0a2-6d207b0c8d89"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{g}.process("\u0ab9\u0abf\u0aaa\u0acd\u0ab8")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

> **Important notice**: only the pdf export will be correct!

**Pdf result**

[image: result]

## Strategy 2: Switch the text if you export to pdf

Before exporting via java if you need to generate pdf, switch the text in the `JasperPrint` object before exporting

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(), theDatasource);
IndicLigaturizer g = new GujaratiLigaturizer();
for (JRPrintPage page : print.getPages()) {
    for (JRPrintElement element : page.getElements()) {
        if (element instanceof JRTemplatePrintText){
            JRTemplatePrintText text = (JRTemplatePrintText)element;
            text.setText(g.process(text.getText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @peter i am getting this error when i tried to preview java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load classes from default package (GujaratiLigaturizer).
After implementing above.

Comment: @PranavShah, you need to add itext5 to your classpath

Comment: yes i did downlaod it from here  and then add to class path... inTools-->option-> JasperReportProperties http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloaditextpdf506sourcesjar.htm
After that created a variable which will have values as you stated Variable Class = GujaratiLigaturizer and initialValueExpression = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.languages.GujaratiLigaturizer

Comment: @PranavShah Hmm, that is the source you need the bin https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/, the official is on github but I do not know where... (sourceforge is just a backup but will serve you well)

Comment: i got this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load classes from default package (GujaratiLigaturizer)

Comment: You still have same problem you need to download the lib, add it to classpath (in jasper studio if displaying in jasper studio), in jasper-report-server (under WEB-INF) if using in jasper report server ecc.

Comment: Or you can check here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JY8wUYKI8-FlGItYpdRPCNNQmm4WJHQuoi5CHgz5wes/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: in ireport tools>>Options>>Classpath add itextpdf-5.5.5.jar, close ireport and reopen. (but this will only solve the problem of exporting to pdf from ireport), you need to do it where your application is deployed.

Comment: can you make edits in above docs <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL10}]]></textFieldExpression>
i wanted to call $V{g}.process($F{COL10}) is it right way or not?

Comment: How it is working for you i did manage to successfully call itext 5.5.5 as you said but i am seeing only Wrong Characters...હીપ્સ...

Comment: Check the Docs i had uploaded everything how i am doing it. :)https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JY8wUYKI8-FlGItYpdRPCNNQmm4WJHQuoi5CHgz5wes/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PranavShah, I have added my output related to the jrxml example (example in question). I have hard to check all your values, test mine and see if you get same result (**NOTE: you need to check the pdf result, naturally the preview is not correct**)

Comment: I can only see that it seems similar to your expected result.

Comment: I had tried your way too it also shows me Above PDF result as you mentioned...After Important notice: only the pdf export will be correct!

Comment: This is how you implement  Alexey Subach solutions in jasper reports, note "the implementation is really poor", so if you don't always get correct result it would not surprise me, I have upvoted dada76 answer ; ), upgrade jasper reports.....

Comment: Furthermore Bruno have commented on the other post, telling that they will release a paid version that handles the language correctly.

Comment: Since your very kind response and Limitation of itext now,I am trying in HTML print  but getting Cache data whenever i try to print ....is there any way to clear cache every time users Prints.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: can i use this solution jrxml file i can see only php,asp.net,html4 etc

Comment: use html4, add it to the header of your output

Comment: If you open Tool its say Preview -> Html (Selected)
Now, Three option on top Designer, XML, Preview now where to make changes

Comment: You need to use this property http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.header, search for some examples

Comment: All this properties are available in version 5.5 and above

Comment: Okay sir thank you for your help so far :)
Some how my limitation is such i can not upgrade it.

Comment: One more thing where html 4 option is located

Comment: You set it in head to avoid cache

Comment: Like this IN jrxml i can do this... <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.2100000000000002"/>
 <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
 <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
 <property name="Cache-Control" value="must-revalidate"/>
 <property name="Pragma" value="no-cache"/>
 <property name="Expires" value="0"/>

Can not find html 4 option to make changes in it

Comment: In fact you need to add it to the html header when you export, that is done with that property or by setting this parameter JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER (search some on the issue and try with the parameter

Comment: i am trying to add this property in Tools ->> Jasper Report Properties 
Property : exporter.setParameter.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI
Value : servlets/image?image=
Not Working though i want something similar which will give me the correct output.(Clearing Cache of Html Print).

Comment: I found HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader() can we use this as property and value : no-cache...dont know just guessing !!!

Comment: You need to get the no-cache into the html you are exporting : ), to do this you need to change the header, add it to the header, in old version I believe this is done through the parameter.

Comment: If you have old version can you please copy paste code in docs i have created...as far as i know if i create parameter then it will popup dialog box where i need to insert some value every time.

Comment: Now, it looks like this (my jrxml file) : <parameter name="parameter1" class="HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader()">
  <property name="HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader()" value="no-cache"/>
 </parameter>
Still no luck

Comment: Check out this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612975/jasperreports-exporting-html-modify-default-html-template,  you need to use the old code (in question) set the parameter as the header you like. This comment thread is getting a bit to long and far from the original question

Comment: Yes i did  follow below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612975/jasperreports-exporting-html-modify-default-html-template
After following it i implement within boundaries of Jasper soft. Result jrxml is this :  <parameter name="parameter1" class="HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader()"> <property name="HtmlExporterConfiguration.getHtmlHeader()" value="no-cache"/> </parameter>

Comment: Can we pass random Parameter with image which will clean cache...Something like Math.random()+$F{value}.....as in Image Expression...i am trying above(not working) but i need a right way to pass random parameter with Value.

Answer (score 2):

Try JasperReports 6.2.0 or newer.  It comes with PDF support for Indic scripts (achieved by transporting the AWT text layout to PDF).

The Unicode report sample (under demo/samples/unicode) from the JasperReports distribution shows texts in several Indic scripts, including Gujarati (using Google Noto fonts).

Comment: i can use only uptill version 5.1.

Comment: @PranavShah, since the "the implementation is really poor" (it works with your example, but maybe with some other it do not), I really suggest you update jasper reports and use this approach.

Comment: @PranavShah I think you posted on the wrong question, the comment does not seem related to the topic.

Comment: Created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710290/how-to-pass-math-random-parameter-to-clear-cache-from-with-in-jasper-report-ve