# Why is the Gujarati-Indian text not rendered correctly using Arial Unicode MS?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

*This is a follow-up on this question [How to export fonts in Gujarati-Indian Language to pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600311/jasper-report-pdf-export-font-of-different-language), [@amedee-van-gasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766786/amedee-van-gasse), QA Engineer at iText [asked me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600311/jasper-report-pdf-export-font-of-different-language?noredirect=1#comment60879352_36600311) to post a question specific to itext with relevant mcve.*

Why is this sequence of unicode `\u0ab9\u0abf\u0aaa\u0acd\u0ab8` not rendered correctly?

It should be rendered like this:

હિપ્સ , also tested with [unicode-converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

However **this code** (example adapted form [iText: Chapter 11: Choosing the right font](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11))

```
public class FontTest {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "fontTest.pdf";
    /** the text to render. */
    public static final String TEST = "\u0ab9\u0abf\u0aaa\u0acd\u0ab8";

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
            "ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
        ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        column.setSimpleColumn(36, 730, 569, 36);
        column.addElement(new Paragraph(TEST, font));
        column.go();
        document.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new FontTest().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
}
```

Generates this **result**:

[image: pdf output]

That looks different from

> હિપ્સ

I have test with `itextpdf-5.5.4.jar`,`itextpdf-5.5.9.jar` and also `itext-2.1.7.js3.jar` (distributed with jasper-reports)

The font used it the one distributes with MS Office `ARIALUNI.TTF` and it can be download from here [Arial Unicode MS](http://www.myfontfree.com/arial-unicode-ms-myfontfreecom126f36926.htm) <sup>*Maybe there are some legal issues downloading see Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans comment</sup>

Comment: Note that your download link is ... not 100% legal. Arial Unicode comes bundled with Microsoft Office for free, but that doesn't make the font itself free. If you look at http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial-unicode, it's quite clear that this is a *very expensive font* (US$370 for the two families, if you didn't buy Office).

Comment: Another question is who is the problem here - what text shaper does iText rely on, and have you tried seeing what *it* does when presented with the Unicode sequence and font resource? This could be iText, but it could also be whatever Java shaper iText relies on.

Comment: FYI only: Guajarati requires reordering the glyphs *before* the font's own OpenType features are applied. There is no code inside that font file to reorder; it's left to the renderer software to preprocess the string first. See also [Microsoft's notes on Gujarati](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenTypeDev/gujarati/intro.htm#reor).

Comment: iText(Sharp) currently doesn't support ligatures. The next version of iTextSharp (to be presented at the Great Indian Developer Summit in Bangalore in about a week) will support ligatures, but the typography addon that will add this support will not be offered as open source. We decided to make it a closed source, commercial addon because too many people think that open source is a synonym of "free of charge" (which it isn't).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bruno, message received, good luck at Summit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither iText5 nor iText2 (which is a very outdated version by the way) support rendering of Indic scripts, no matter which font you select.

Rendering Indic scripts is not similar to any Latin scripts, because a long series of additional actions should be taken to get the correct result, e.g. some characters need to be reordered first according to the language rules.

This is a known issue to iText company.

There is a stub implementation for Gujaranti in iText5 called GujaratiLigaturizer, but the implementation is really poor and you cannot expect to get correct results with it.

You can try to process your string with this ligaturizer and then output the resultant string in the following way:

```
IndicLigaturizer g = new GujaratiLigaturizer();
String processed = g.process(inputString);
// proceed with the processed string
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test it, do you know of any better implementations, FYI the older version (itext2) because this is distributed with latest jasper report distribution (I think they had some problem with pdf/a or legal issue).

Comment: thanx a ton.. wasted a lot of hours trying to find a fix...

Answer (score 0):

Build your application using latest typography jar file that
Will solve your problem of Gujarati font rendering in pdf 
In itext.