# Jasper reports font rendering issue

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have a really strange issue with my fonts rendering in Tamil when I generate a PDF using Jasper Reports. 
It flips two letters around. 
The test that I am trying to render is

> வழங்கிய தேத

but when the PDF renders it flips it around

> [image: Incorrect rendering]

Strangely if I copy it to clipboard its almost back to normal

> வழங்கிய தேதி

I am using

> net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.ireportfamily_arialuni=reports/fonts/fontsfamily_arialuni.xml
>
> ```
>           <textField>
>                 <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="80" height="15" forecolor="#A0A5B2" uuid="d5a7ab5b-bf11-487d-981a-ba64413bc33e"/>
>                 <textElement>
>                     <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" size="9"/>
>                 </textElement>
>                 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT}.findLabel("DATE OF ISSUE")]]></textFieldExpression>
>             </textField>
> ```

Whenever 2 letters combined to form a single letter, the first 2 characters gets swapped
Similarly, whenever 3 letters combine to form a single letter, the first 2 character gets swapped

Comment: You should look at [Why is the Gujarati-Indian text not rendered correctly using Arial Unicode MS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36655923/876298) & [Font (Myanmar3) not rendering correctly in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34295596/876298)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the answer posted by Alex K it led me to check if I was on the latest version of jasperreports.

It turns out that I was a version behind and in version 6.7.0 this issue has been resolved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```