# Why are Hindi Fonts not rendered correctly?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf, dynamic-reports

When I am generating pdf from .jrxml file using java, hindi fonts are not printing correctly.

eg :

```
रक्त is printing as रक् त
दैनिक is printing as दैनकि
```

I have set font in pdf using jasper properties :

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name",JASPER_PDF_FONT_FILE);

JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding","Identity-H");
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded","true");
```

I am not getting why it is printing like this.

I am using JasperReports not iText.

Comment: This are related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600311/how-to-export-fonts-in-gujarati-indian-language-to-pdf and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287186/how-can-i-render-hindi-correctly-when-exporting-to-pdf/34287509#34287509, since you should use font-extension, but the problem here is that itext lib probably can't render that text, see the different answers for a solution

Comment: @Petter Friberg : What exactly the problem is in my code?

Comment: What exact language are you using?, itext the library that create's pdf can't render Ligaturizer correctly, see the answer on post to find a work around

Comment: I have seen your edit to post, Note: jasper-reports uses **itext** to generate the pdf

Comment: jasper reports with java

Comment: you can try your font directly with itext see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf

Comment: Thank You :) Its working when using                                                   String TEST = "रक्त दैनिक";                                                           IndicLigaturizer indicLigaturizer = new DevanagariLigaturizer();
String processed = indicLigaturizer.process(TEST);                                          Is there any solution that can support all languages?

Comment: "all languages, I do not really know", but latest version of jasper-reports uses a new method to go around the problem of itext. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36688145/5292302

Comment: दैनिक is printing as दैनकि correctly but still रक्त is printing as रक् त , हिन्दी is printing as हिन् दी. Half letters(HALANT) is not printing correctly

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Can you please help for HALANT hindi letters?        
दैनिक is printing as दैनकि correctly but still रक्त is printing as रक् त , हिन्दी is printing as हिन् दी. Half letters(HALANT) is not printing correctly

Comment: You can try with different fonts, but I think the best solution is to upgrade to latest see jasper-report see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600311/how-to-export-fonts-in-gujarati-indian-language-to-pdf/36688145#36688145

Comment: Solved this issue using JasperReports 6.2.2 with fonts Noto Sans and exported font using jasperreports_extension.properties

Comment: Perfect great!, have fun!