# How to use gujrati font In jasper Report with Java

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have installed shrti.ttl in iReport Tool and export extenstion as Jar of this to use this In java code.

Its properly display content in iReport, but when I exportReportToPdf in java code ...its properly not displaying content

some two three words are displaying not properly

In iReport it appear correctly as below

[image]

and when I export as PDF it appear wrong as below

[image]

kindly suggestion for this.

Comment: Try doing the same thing in the latest Jaspersoft Studio, recent JR versions have better support for Indic scripts in PDF.

Comment: Probably related [how-to-export-fonts-in-gujarati-indian-language-to-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36600311/5292302), due to itext limitations you need to use later versions of jasper-reports or use a 1/2 working workaround that maybe will not always guarantee correct result.